# Setting products with Dynamic Tag Management?

Tags: adobe-analytics

I can set events through pageload rules but how do I set s.products? I'm trying to pass along product info with the purchase events but I don't see how to set this through DTM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DTM currently does not offer a built-in form field for `s.products`.  However, you can add it yourself.

Within the rule, go to **Adobe Analytics > Custom Page Code** and click on the **Open Editor** button.

Within this text box, you can write arbitrary javascript, including setting any Adobe Analytics variable.

If you need to reference a data element, you can use `_satellite.getVar('data element name')`